# How to connect customer to account?

Tags: stripe-payments

As I understand, when I want to take money, I take them from customer object and when I want to give money I direct them to account object.
I created customer_1 and customer_2 via 2 different tokens

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers \
   -u sk_test_BQokikJOvBiI2HlWgH4olfQ2: \
   -d description="Customer for addison.taylor@example.com" \
   -d source=tok_189gHx2eZvKYlo2CzA1hApdo
```

Then I created account_1 and account_2 via

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/accounts \
   -u sk_test_qoHbcUFCbOA41F3BRm2OlgdT: \
   -d type=standard \
   -d country=US \
   -d email="bob@example.com"
```

Now customer_2 buys something from customer_1
And I have to specify customer_2.customer_id and customer_1.account_id
thus found are sent to account_1, but I dont understand how can I link customer_1 and account_1 together

Comment: I think I answered you on IRC but just in case: to be paid, each customer needs their own Stripe Account: https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a charge, you specify the customer and the source id (card's id).  You can also add a "destination" parameter, which would be equal to the account you want to send the money to. You will also specify an application fee.  Stripe fees are first taken from this application fee (loosely, they're actually just removed straight from your account, and the application fee goes to your account, so when you do the math, the amount that goes to your accounts is the application fee - stripe fees).

Also, you can set an e-mail on the Users when you create them, which is useful because it'll automatically email the default e-mail on file with the receipt for every charge and refund.